# Trouble Appending to Lists Embedded in Lists

Tags: python, list

I am trying to append values to a list with embedded lists in Python. In the code snippet below I am stuck at the point where I try to ensure the value of x is appended to list_numbers, but I also want it to only append to list_numbers based on correspondence with list_letters.

```
list_letters = [A,B,C]
list_numbers = [1]
list_of_lists = [[list_letter],[list_number]

for letter in list_letters:
    value = x
    "Append x to the end of list_numbers that corresponds to letter in list_letters"
```

The list of list aspect of Python seems to be confusing me. I am wondering if I have set up my lists wrong. Any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: "but I also want it to only append to list_numbers based on correspondence with list_letters" what does this mean?

Comment: Maybe lists are n't the tool for your job. You are aware that Python has dictionaries, aren't you?

Comment: you have a syntax error in your code. You're missing a bracket and the end of your initialization for `list_of_lists`

Comment: Could you clarify what you're intending to do? what's the correspondence between list_letters and list_numbers? the index? the ascii code? What is value? Did you forgot the quotes around the letters?

Comment: Is this pseudo code? what does the string at the end mean?

Comment: You need a minimal *working* example.  What you've written won't even get past the first line.  Try to improve that, and we might be able to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python dictionary will do a better mapping between strings and values.

```
myd = {"A": 1, "B": 2, "C": 0}
myd["C"] = 3
myd.update({"D": 4}) # this will add D
```

The solution with lists for your question is like:

```
X = ["A", "B", "C"]
Y = [1]
Z = [X, Y]
for i in X:
    val = X.index(i) + 1
    if val not in Y:
        Y.append(val)
```